# Need Linux Distro for Acer R7 (10-point touch)

Tags: linux, linux-distribution

I have an Acer R7 laptop that has been my faithful companion for nearly a decade. It has great specs for it’s vintage, including 8GB RAM and a 512GB SSD, 10-point touch with full HD and more. But it has met its match with Windows 10 v2004 and is too slow to be productive with modern security enabled.

I like Windows 10 a lot, so keeping that familiarity would be great.  Main workload is RDP to my monster dev machine, and local browsing.

Comment: Do you have any specific requirements beyond the usual "What is the best Linux distro?"

Comment: Yes, support touch screen with gestures, work seamlessly with core i5 integrated graphics.

Answer (score 1):

Any GNOME-based distro has basic touchscreen gesture support. There might be a bit of fiddling required to get multitouch drivers to work correctly.

I'm guessing i5 integrated graphics are popular enough to be well-supported out of the box on any reasonably popular distro.

In general, there is not much difference between distros in terms of hardware spport, as much of this development is done in the kernel. It boils down to which distro you seem to like best. If you're looking for something similar to Windows 10, you might want to have look at [Linux Mint](https://linuxmint.com/).

Comment: I think "Linus Mint" should be "Linux Mint". Otherwise a nice answer.